# How do I return a datatype as a return object in scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, generics, user-defined-functions

I want to return a datatype as a return value of a function in scala. I tried the below function.

```
def typeGetterFun(`type`: DataType) = `type` match {
      case StringType => String
      case LongType => Long
      case IntegerType => Int
    }
```

Error:

```
 error: object java.lang.String is not a value
             case StringType => String
```

I also tried using type tag Which did not work either

```
    def typeGetter(`type`:DataType): Any = `type` match {
      case StringType => universe.TypeTag[String]
      case x:DecimalType => universe.TypeTag[java.math.BigDecimal]
      case LongType => universe.TypeTag[Long]
      case IntegerType => universe.TypeTag[Int]
    }
```

We need to pass mirror and another parameter for apply method it seems.

I'm not sure how to do that. I Want a generic one like what I'm trying above.

Comment: How are you going to _use_ that function? Your declared return type `Any` isn't useful for anything meaningful.

Comment: `classOf[String]`?

Comment: What is the actual meta-problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to guess how you're going to use the function.

Depending on your use case you can try `Type`

```
def typeGetter(`type`: DataType): universe.Type = `type` match {
  case StringType => universe.typeOf[String]
  case x: DecimalType => universe.typeOf[java.math.BigDecimal]
  case LongType => universe.typeOf[Long]
  case IntegerType => universe.typeOf[Int]
}
```

or `TypeTag`

```
def typeGetter(`type`: DataType): universe.TypeTag[_] = `type` match {
  case StringType => universe.typeTag[String]
  case x: DecimalType => universe.typeTag[java.math.BigDecimal]
  case LongType => universe.typeTag[Long]
  case IntegerType => universe.typeTag[Int]
}
```

or `Class`

```
def typeGetter(`type`: DataType): Class[_] = `type` match {
  case StringType => classOf[String]
  case x: DecimalType => classOf[java.math.BigDecimal]
  case LongType => classOf[Long]
  case IntegerType => classOf[Int]
}
```

or `ClassTag`

```
def typeGetter(`type`: DataType): scala.reflect.ClassTag[_] = `type` match {
  case StringType => scala.reflect.classTag[String]
  case x: DecimalType => scala.reflect.classTag[java.math.BigDecimal]
  case LongType => scala.reflect.classTag[Long]
  case IntegerType => scala.reflect.classTag[Int]
}
```

or a type class

```
trait TypeGetter[T] {
  type Out
}
object TypeGetter {
  type Aux[T, Out0] = TypeGetter[T] { type Out = Out0 }
    
  implicit val string: Aux[StringType, String] = null
  implicit val decimal: Aux[DecimalType, BigDecimal] = null
  implicit val long: Aux[LongType, Long] = null
  implicit val integer: Aux[IntegerType, Int] = null
}
  
def foo[T](implicit typeGetter: TypeGetter[T]): typeGetter.Out = ???
```